# Multiple Forms with same content boxes on one page

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I'm looking for a solution to generate multiple forms on one page, that contain the same checkboxes and fields. For now, when I create those forms, even if I use different form names, all checkboxes with the same name get checked at the same time.
What I am trying to do is the following. I do have an events-list. Every event should have a form attached. Every form has some text and some checkboxes. But when I'm trying to check some boxes in my second form, it jumps to the first one (because of the same name of the checkbox).

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" />
</form>
<form method="post" name="form2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" />
</form>
```

Is there a way to get this working? Or do I have to use unique checkbox names, even if the formnames are unique? Which would make it more complex when I have a variable count of forms / events.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically bind form elements i.e checkboxes. Don't include it in HTML code. This can be done with Jquery $.html() function to bind checkboxes to forms at runtime.

I guess this happens because form1 overrides form2 elements due to same names and id of checkboxes.

Or Try to use 4 different id of all checkboxes, and different id's of form names.

Hope it may work.

Happy Coding!

Atul Jindal